# How to add arabic and english language in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Iam working on codeignator website, where arabic and english languages are needed.Is it by using any language file? Can anyone help me out of this..

Thanks.

Comment: check this [language class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is by using language file. When you want localization the text in the view should be retrieved from language file.

```
 $this->lang->line('language_key');
```

In the language file you will have the actual message to the key.

```
 $lang['language_key'] = "The actual message to be shown";
```

Then you need to load the proper language file.

```
 $this->lang->load('filename', 'language');
```

filename : Name of the file inside the language folder.
language: Folder name for the language

Answer (score 0):

In the language file, you can copy the English folder, and rename is and the just follow the http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html

Also in the config/config.php you can set your default language. Very simple stuff.